# EBNF for simple conditions

Tags: bnf, ebnf

I'm trying to write a EBNF specification for a simple expression of condition-statements similar to that within if statement tests, for example: `aaa = "xxx"` or `aaa != "xxx" AND bbb = "yyy"` or more complex with parentheses like `aaa = "xxx" AND bbb = "yyy" AND ( ccc = "zzz" OR ddd = "www" )`

The spec I've come up with so far is this, and my question - is it correct?

```
<cond> ::= <id> <rel_op> <value>
    | <cond> <op> <cond>
    | "(" <cond> ")"

<op> ::= AND
    | OR

<rel_op> ::= "=" 
    | "!="

<value> ::= <quot> <char>* <quot>

<quot> ::= "
```

Side-note - I'm new to E/BNF and planning on implementing a parser in C# based on this specification to replace an old parser that is spaghetti-like and stinks.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I came up with, and has also implemented successfully:

```
<cond> := <rel_cond> {<op> <cond>} 
    | <parenth_cond> {<op> <cond>}

<rel_cond> := <id> <rel_op> <value>

<rel_op> := "=" | "!=" | "~" | "!~"

<parenth_cond> := "(" <cond> ")"

<op> := AND | OR

<id> := <char>* 

<value> := <quot> <char>* <quot>

<quot> := "
```